How to use kotlinx.serialization without build tools (Maven, Gradle, and so on)?
I'm interested in using kotlinx.serialization in my project, but it wasn't built by any of the build tools (Maven, Gradle, something else). I have access to the classes and annotations, but when it comes to @Serializable annotation, I get next warning:

kotlinx.serialization compiler plugin is not applied to the module, so this annotation would not be processed. Make sure that you've setup your buildscript correctly and re-import project.

In order to solve this problem, I tried 2 ways:

Download the JAR files from Maven repository;
Add the libraries via Open Module Settings > Libraries > New Project Library (plus sign).

But I still keep getting this warning. Maybe, there's something that I did wrong?

I never tried this myself, but you probably need to download this jar: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-serialization-compiler-plugin and then pass this argument to kotlinc command: -Xplugin=kotlinx-serialization-compiler-plugin.jar. It may be not a full answer, you need to experiment with this.

How can I access kotlinc?

Depending on how you build your project. Pretty much every build tool uses the kotlinc underneath.

I tried to pass this argument via Open Module Settings > Facets > Additional command line parameters and Project settings, but when I try to rebuild the project, I get Kotlin: Plugin classpath entry points to a non-existent location: kotlin-serialization-compiler-plugin-1.9.20.jar  error. The kotlin-serialization-compiler-plugin-1.9.20.jar file is located in the root directory
